# Link to same page using div class

Tags: html

I am posting the code. In the line `<div class='qrcode-value'></div>` it will scan the qr code and I want to make it as link so that it will redirect to the other website once clicking on it. Instead of copy and paste.

```
<div id="content-overlay" style='display: none'>
    <div class='qrcode-value'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use JavaScript `onclick="location.href = 'www.xyz.com';"`. Read more about `onclick` event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<a href="http://google.com">
  <div class='qrcode-value'>
     anything
  </div>
</a>
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/r73pn4w8/2/

Comment: yeah how can I help you @CodeIt

Comment: No help needed at the moment.

Comment: @marcelo I want to make the link connection dynamically. Thannk you so much for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do this.

```
<div id="content-overlay" style='display: none'>
  <div class='qrcode-value' onclick="location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946816/link-to-same-page-using-div-class';">
  </div>
</div>
```

Read more about onclick event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick).

Comment: @Codelt Thank you so much I will try to run this code